# Query data every time or store values in table?

Tags: sql, database, performance

I have a table of `players` with a field called `scores`. Players gain different scores at different games. Every few moments, I want to know total score gained by a certain player until then.

Note that I want to do this action frequently.

The question is, which way should I choose?
1) Define a field in my users table as `player_score` and update it after each game finishes.
2) Every time I want to calculate total score of a player, query on all of the games and sum up the scores gained until now.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You can mix the two approaches; have a table for scores in each game, and a trigger that updates an overall score. How many times a second are you going to want to query this data?

Comment: @CaiusJard I think once a second is good for a game.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was going to be thousands of times a second... it might be better to just keep the score history, index it well and sum it whenever you need. It reduces complexity and the once-a-second load isn't very punishing to the server. If it did grow big you can consider something like Redis caching to help out too

Comment: @CaiusJard Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much registrers you have on table games. If you have too many records select will take longer.

Comment: Yeah there are lots of players in this game. I guess I should go with what @CaiusJard says.